Does "DNS provider" refer to an authoritative DNS server or a DNS resolver?
I'm trying to understand the term "DNS provider" and what exactly it refers to. When someone mentions a "DNS provider," are they typically referring to an Authoritative DNS server or a DNS (recursive) resolver? Or is it a more general term referring to a provider of any sort of DNS service?

It depends on context, though almost always it refers to some specific kind. In general conversation it's much more likely to refer to a DNS resolver (i.e. provider of DNS resolving/caching service), while in hosting-related discussions it can refer to a provider of authoritative DNS hosting for one's domain.

People - even technical ones - mix these up all the time.  If you were just talking to someone, you might have to ask them to be 100% sure what they mean.

I disagree about the "general conversation" context.  Most people are "provided with" recursive DNS service by their ISP, or at least by the DNS servers assigned via their CPE and the question would rarely come up.   In my world (I'm a DNS head) a DNS provider is an authoritative provider, i.e. the party responsible for hosting your domain.

@Alnitak Many people make use of services like Google Public DNS. In that context, Google would be their DNS provider, instead of their ISP.
